# How to achieve this kind of color effect (colors in "anarchic grid")?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, grids

I'm trying to get a result close to the one below in Illustrator, but I never end up with a satisfactory result.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/dx8UnVL.jpg]

I think this kind of logos was pretty popular some time ago, with vivid colors and maybe a result a little different.

Do someone could have a tutorial to achieve that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Can you show us your unsatisfactory results? It'd be helpful to see where you're getting stuck so we know specifically what to help improve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this logo is using overlapping 1-3 shapes per "location" with various **blending modes** (probably overlay and multiply are used). Also may be using **opacity and/or transparency mask**.
It's hard to tell exactly what you should do just by looking - you should cycle between those blending modes individually per shape/s for every location.